# git ignore all but one type of file, anywhere down

Tags: git, ignore

My goal is to write a .gitignore file that will ignore everything at any level downwards except:

```
*.xxx
*.yyy
```

in the current directory (where the .gitignore is located) and

```
*.xxx
```

anywhere -at any level- in the tree below.

In other words, I want to keep in git `*.xxx` at any level as well as `*.yyy` at the 'root' level. Anything else should be ignored.

The name of the subfolders is unknown, so I cannot quote them in the gitignore file.

I have tried many alternatives, with no success so far:
For instance:

```
#ignore everything in any subdirectory
*
*/**
#expect some files:
!*.yyy
!*/**/*.xxx
```

I think I am hitting the restriction:

> "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that
>   file is excluded"

in the git ignore doc... Is there a way to work-around this...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is indeed with the blacklisting of all the subdirectories at first and afterwards trying to re-include some of the content within those directories.

The solution to this is whitelisting the subdirectories again before trying to re-include the files:

```
# blacklist everything
*

# whitelist all content ending with slash (directories)
!/**/

# finally whitelist all files with valid extension in the entire repo
!*.xxx
!*.yyy
# ignoring the ones that are only allowed within the repo root
*/**/*.yyy
```

Comment: Seems to work indeed, thx... Can you comment on the logic to reach there?

Comment: Sure thing, answer is updated. Let me know if you need a more detailed explanation!